# Parse anonymous login (Guest user)

Tags: flutter, authentication, parse-platform, backend, back4app

I am making a mobile app using Flutter sdk, which requires me to allow a guest user enter into pages wihtout login id.
So, I am seeking something like anonymous user login or auto-generate a user with random username.
I am using [parse_server_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/parse_server_sdk).

In the [api documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/parse_server_sdk/latest/flutter_parse_sdk/ParseUser/loginAnonymous.html), I found a function called loginAnonymous() in class ParseUser.
But the class constructor itself requires username & password for instantiation.

So, it defeats the purpose of my use-case.
Please let me know how to get around this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried providing null as the username as well as the password and email?
I am not using `loginAnonymous()`, but this should work:

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser(null, null, null);
await parseUser.loginAnonymous();
```

EDIT:

This should work, too.

```
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.forQuery();
await parseUser.loginAnonymous();
```